# Not able to retrieve $_POST values through ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, html, jquery

I am having little problem with ajax. Here is my code what I have done so far:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    getLocation();
});

function getLocation()
{
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
function showPosition(position)
{
    latitude =position.coords.latitude;
    longitude= position.coords.longitude;
    $.post({ url: 'test.php',
    data : ({lat :latitude,long:longitude}),
    success: function(data){
        alert('done');
    }});

}
```

What I am trying to do is call the function on document ready and trying to retrieve the value of ajax call on the same file where I did call this script. Whenever I reload the page, I don't get any value of :

```
print_r($_POST['lat']);
```

I don't know what is the actual problem,I already checked in console and didn't get any error. Please help.

Comment: Actually you should not see it when you **reload** the page. The `$_POST['lat']` is available on server-side PHP-script called by AJAX-request.

Comment: @zavg You are correct but as I mentioned above i need to get that value on the same page where i did call that script.Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: jcubic is right, try to print your data. If it is not returned, check if you send the request in Firebug or Chrome developer tools (Network section)

Comment: @zavg When I alert data in success it will show the hole page. But I want to read the value of the Lat,long into my file, But it's not showing ,can you tell me what is exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by own. Here what I have done. I made one more file called `test2.php` and put my php script over there and call that file in my ajax call. Here the code.

**Test.php**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    getLocation();
});

function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    latitude =position.coords.latitude;
    longitude= position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({ url: 'test2.php',
    data : ({lat :latitude,long:longitude}),
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
        if(data=='true'){
            window.location = "http://example.com";
        }
    }
    });
}   
</script>
```

**Test2.php**

```
//just for example
<?php 
   echo 'true';
?>
```

Hope this will help someone in future.

Answer (score 3):

To get the value you need to print it in success callback

```
$.post({ url: 'test.php',
    data : ({lat :latitude,long:longitude}),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and if you put

```
if (isset($_POST['lat']) {
    print_r($_POST['lat']);
}
```

you will get the value in alert box.

**EDIT**: You can check in php if the reqest came from Ajax using this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    if (isset($_POST['lat']) {
        print_r($_POST['lat']);
    }
    exit();
}
```

if you put this at the begining you will see only that `print_r` from ajax call.

Comment: Yes ,when I alert this then whole script will show on it,But how can i show it to on the same page.

Comment: Yes ,i get that value on, but i want to know that is there any way to get this result on the same page.

Comment: @Toretto only if you don't use Ajax. you need to post normal form. Or insert that data into your html using `$('body').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');`

Comment: Actually i need to pass that value in curl, so all i need to get on the same page,if the condition will satisfied then redirect user to specific page. Any solution would be helpful.

Comment: @Toretto then just put your curl code in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` check, along with rediretion, you don't need to print it. you already have it in php.

Comment: can you please show me how can i use that value in curl url.Here is the code where I need to use that value `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=lat value here,long value here');`.

Comment: @Toretto `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=' . $_POST['lat'] . ',' . $_POST['long']);`

Comment: I already tried it but it doesn't work for the same page(file).But I tried something else to achieve this and it's work for me.Thanks for your support, I appreciate it, +1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are printing is not an array. So you have to print it like,

```
print $_POST['lat'];
```

(OR)

```
echo $_POST['lat'];
```

AND NOT

```
print_r($_POST['lat']);
```

If you want to print all post values mean then you can print it as,

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: just a remark: print_r will perform a normal print on non array/object types (but ofc it shouldn't be used for that :))